# Replace all x and y fields in a file in bash

Tags: bash, field, masking

I have a file separated by colons such as this

```
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10
11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20
```

etc

always the same amount of fields in each line

I want to be able to mask (replace the field with a *) the xth and yth fields of each line of that file. Let's say I want to mask 5th and 7th fields so that the file then looks like :

```
1:2:3:4:*:6:*:8:9:10
11:12:13:14:*:16:*:18:19:20
```

How can I achieve such a thing in bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Something like this to get you started

```
#!/bin/bash

x=5
y=7

awk -F':' -vX="$x" -vY="$y" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$X="*";$Y="*"}{print}' input
```

output:

```
$ ./fields.sh 
1:2:3:4:*:6:*:8:9:10
11:12:13:14:*:16:*:18:19:20
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just to learn, why do you need the `OFS=FS` piece?

Comment: `OFS` is the OutputFieldSeparator, which by default is space, If I don't set it to the same value that is used for splitting up the fields then the output would have looked like this `1 2 3 4 * 6 * 8 9 10`

Answer (score 2):

A bash solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -a arr
do
         arr[4]='*'
         arr[6]='*'
         (IFS=":";echo "${arr[*]}")
done < file
```

Comment: Why does `IFS=":" echo "${arr[*]}"` not work, but `(IFS=":";echo "${arr[*]}")` does? I tested that it does not work, even if I use `command echo` instead of `echo`.

Comment: `IFS=A eval 'echo "${arr[*]}"'` would work, but eval is evil, so not recommended. & that would cause a sub-program anyway.

Comment: @anishsane That's a perfectly fine usage for `eval`. Some find it unclear (I'm used to recognizing correct quoting). Usually I'd just use a function + local. I've been meaning to edit that wiki example with some corrections for a while... finally got around to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a sed one-liner. (bash variable part is ignored, I used hardcoded value 5 and 7 just for example)

```
sed -r 's/[^:]+:/*:/5;s/[^:]+:/*:/7' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10
11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20"|sed -r 's/[^:]+:/*:/5;s/[^:]+:/*:/7' 
1:2:3:4:*:6:*:8:9:10
11:12:13:14:*:16:*:18:19:20
```

with variable:

```
sed -r "s/[^:]+:/*:/$X;s/[^:]+:/*:/$Y" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ed:

```
 $ printf '%s\n' '1,$ g/./s/\(\([[:digit:]*]*\(:\|$\)\)\{'{4,6}'\}\)[[:digit:]*]*:/\1\*:/' ,p |
 ed -s <(xclip -o)
1:2:3:4:*:6:*:8:9:10
11:12:13:14:*:16:*:18:19:20
```

w to write out the file.